# JavaScript global dynamic variable undefined from function to function, seems to be local scope

Tags: javascript, scope, global-variables, undefined, dynamic-variables

I'm having an issue with the interaction of these two functions.  They are used in onclick calls of elements.  Essentially (because of things outside my control) I need to remember when and what has hidden an element.

Everything is working exactly as I want, except for the undefined check in the show function.  I create a global variable when I hide things and I want to use that again when I'm looking to show things.  The only issue I have is that in the show function, it seems what I thought was a global variable is not.

```
function branchShow(targetID, triggerID){
    var target = document.getElementById(targetID);
    var trigger = document.getElementById(triggerID);
    var parentID = trigger.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.id;
    var globalMemory = "wasIHiddenBefore_" + parentID

    if (typeof window[globalMemory] !== "undefined"){
        if (window[globalMemory]) {
            console.log(globalMemory + " is evaluated true");
            window[globalMemory] = false;
        } else {
            console.log(globalMemory + " is evaluated false");
            target.setAttribute("style","display: block;");
        }
    } else {
        console.log(globalMemory + " is undefined");
        target.setAttribute("style","display: block;");
    }
};

function branchHide(targetID, triggerID){
    if (typeof i !== "undefined" ) {var iMemory = i;}
    if (typeof j !== "undefined" ) {var jMemory = j;}
    if (typeof k !== "undefined" ) {var kMemory = k;}
    var target = document.getElementById(targetID);
    target.setAttribute("style","display: none;");

    //don't want to flag on load
    if (hasLoadFinished){
        window["wasIHiddenBefore_" + targetID] == true;
        console.log("wasIHiddenBefore_" + targetID + " created as true");
    }
    .
    .
    .
```

The console output from a sample execution is below.  The 4th and the 6th line are the most critical in displaying the issue.

```
wasIHiddenBefore_1e16f2513f7842d5be352ca01b5c1c3f is undefined
wasIHiddenBefore_f82bdc0c527541e68fc405e9ac70015b is undefined
wasIHiddenBefore_2d869e44f4c44454a8415eecbd64061e created as true
wasIHiddenBefore_f82bdc0c527541e68fc405e9ac70015b created as true
wasIHiddenBefore_1e16f2513f7842d5be352ca01b5c1c3f is undefined
wasIHiddenBefore_f82bdc0c527541e68fc405e9ac70015b is undefined
```

Does anyone know why I'm seeing what I'm seeing and what I can do to make these dynamic variables act globally from function to function?  Thanks.

Comment: What is expected result of `window["wasIHiddenBefore_" + targetID] == true;`?

Comment: I expect to create a dynamic variable "wasIHiddenBefore_f82bdc0c527541e68fc405e9ac70015b" from the console output that holds the value true.  I want nothing more than a global boolean with a name I can't know ahead of time.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `window["wasIHiddenBefore_" + targetID] == true` checks if `window["wasIHiddenBefore_" + targetID]` is equal to `true`, though does not set `window["wasIHiddenBefore_" + targetID]` to `true`, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Equality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window["wasIHiddenBefore_" + targetID] == true;` is a comparison, not an assignment. Despite logging "*… created as true*" you never set the variable. You want `window["wasIHiddenBefore_" + targetID] = true;`.

Comment: omfg, im so sorry.  i regret everything.